# How to setup properties on CSV import in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, csv, orientdb

I have a CSV file like:

```
FN        |  MI  |  LN      |  ADDR          |  CITY      |  ZIP     |  GENDER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Patricia  |      |  Faddar  |  7063 Carr xxx |  Carolina  |  00979-7033 | F
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lui       |  E   |  Baves   |  PO Box xxx    |  Boqueron  |  00622-1240 | F
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Janine    |  S   |  Perez   |  25 Calle xxx  |  Salinas   |  00751-3332 | F
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rose      |      |  Mary    |  229 Calle xxx |  Aguadilla |  00603-5536 | F
```

And I am importing it into OrientDB like:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/sample.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "Users" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/orientdb/databases/test",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "Users", "extends": "V"}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to set the import so that it created properties so that `FN` becomes `first_name`, `MI` becomes `middle_name` and so on, as well as set some values to lowercase. For ex: `Carolina` to become `carolina`

I could probably make this changes from the SCHEMA once the data is added. My reason to do this here is that I have multiple CSV files and I want to keep the the same schema for all

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi 2.2.x

Comment: Please include your solutions as answers rather than as edits to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename a field, take a look at the Field transformer:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transformer.html#field-transformer

Rename the field from salary to renumeration:

```
  { "field": 
    { "fieldName": "remuneration", 
      "expression": "salary"
    } 
  },
  { "field": 
    { "fieldName": "salary", 
      "operation": "remove"
    } 
  }
```

in the same way, you can apply the lowerCase function to the property

`{field: {fieldName:'name', expression: '$input.name.toLowerCase()'}}`

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: this seems to work. any ideas how to set those `fields / columns` as properties? The import comes in with no schema, but i would like to define one.

Comment: read carefully the documentation section about loader:
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Loader.html#orientdb-loader
the flag dbAutoCreateProperties, if set to true, will create the properties of the given class automatically. For more control over the schema, my suggestion is to create it before, maybe using a SQL script  and the LOAD SCRIPT console command: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Load-Script.html